# I accidentally mapped the 'n' command to 'N' and vice versa in vim. What did I do, and how do I reverse it?

Tags: vim, mapping

I have no idea what happened. One second <kbd>n</kbd> would search forward and <kbd>N</kbd> would search backwards and the next, <kbd>n</kbd> would search backwards and <kbd>N</kbd> would search forward.

What could I have possibly done, and how I can I revert back to the normal scheme.

(Note: I made sure that caps locks wasn't on =P )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start your search command with `/` (search forward command) then `n` searches forward and `N` searches backwards. And when you start with `?` (backward search) then `n` search backwards and `N` search forward. See `:help n` and `:help N`.

You can consider `n` as a shorthand for a "*next* matching of the last search in the same direction". `N` has "opposite" meaning, it is common case for Vim one-key moving commands (`w` and `W`, `f` and `F` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

After doing a reverse search, with `?` rather than `/`, `n` will repeat the reverse search and `N` will search forward.